# Keys as Rows (Pandas Dataframe from dictionary)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key, row

I have this dictionary:

```
d = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': (4,5,6)}
```

I would like it to be formed as a dataframe where the key is shown as row along with its corresponding values, like the table below:

| Keys | Values |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

1. Create your dataframe with the following command:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Keys': list(dict.keys()), 'Values': list(dict.values())})`

2. Explode your dataframe on column of 'Values' with the following command:

`df = df.explode(column='Values').reset_index(drop=True`

The output result is something like this:

```
       Keys   Values
  0    a      1
  1    a      2
  2    a      3
  3    b      4
  4    b      5
  5    b      6
```

Comment: You can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to fix the index from `0 0 0 1 1 1` to `0 1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user17242583

Comment: Many thanks my friend worked just fine!

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = {'a': (1,2,3), 'b': (4,5,6)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).unstack().droplevel(1).reset_index().rename({'index':'Keys', 0:'Values'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Keys  Values
0    a       1
1    a       2
2    a       3
3    b       4
4    b       5
5    b       6
```